# Java Webapp Cannot Find Local Server Directory

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, web-applications, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC 3.1 webapp running on Tomcat 5.5 on a CentOS server.  I have a controller that checks for the existence of a file located on a network share, which is mounted on the server (`/netshare/data/`).  My application cannot seem to see this directory, however when I run a standalone java app with the same code, it is able to locate the directory and its contained files without error.  Is there some configuration that needs to be done in Tomcat so that directories outside the webapp can be referenced by Java?

Here is my controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Test")
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showTest(Model model){
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    File dirTest = new File("/netshare/data");

    if (dirTest.isDirectory()){

        messages.add("Base directory found successfully!");

        File dataFileDir = new File("/netshare/data/dataFiles/");
        Integer fileId = 8000;

        File dataFile = new File(dataFileDir, fileId.toString() + ".pdf");
        if (dataFile.exists()){
            messages.add("Data file found!");
        }
        else {
            messages.add("Data file NOT found!");
        }
    }
    else {
        messages.add("Base directory not found!");
    }

    model.addAttribute("messages", messages);
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change this path to point to some local directory?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov By local, do you mean within the webapp folder, or a local filesystem directory (eg. /usr/home) ?

Comment: I mean the second one, f.e. `/usr/home` or `/tmp`.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov The application was able to see `/usr/home` without issue.  The mounted directory should be accessible to all users, but now I'll have to confirm this.

Comment: It realy looks like a permission problem. Try running the standalone program with the same OS user that runs Tomcat. Even accessing the dir from command line should be enough.

Comment: I am going to guess that you are mounting remote fs using nfs, if so make sure the anonuid or anongid in your mount so that tomcat can access it. Also check the directory local mnt directory to make sure that tomcat has access to it.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with Isilon permissions, I'll see if the sysadmins can clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a permissions issue with the Isilon server being accessed by the web server, and not an issue with either my webapp or Tomcat's configuration.  Thank you everyone for the help.